# Objective-C What are the things in parentheses?

Tags: objective-c

in this sample method/message:

```
-(void) setNumerator:(int) n {
    numerator = n;
}
```

What does the (int) mean? It doesn't look like its casting to an int...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`int` refers to the type of `n`.  When sending the `-setNumerator:` message, you need to supply an argument.  In this case you would supply an argument of type `int`.

if your method had a definition like:

```
- (void)setNumerator:(NSNumber *)n {
    NSNumber *newNumerator = [n copy];
    [numerator release];
    numerator = newNumerator;
}
```

you would then supply an `NSNumber` when sending `-setNumerator:`.

Answer (score 0):

The (int) is a type specifier.  It means that the variable (in this case, "n") is of the type "int".